# How do I make a gem with a binary, when it depends on bundler to find its dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem which depends on Bundler's Gemfile to find its dependencies (they are hosted on github:enterprise). I want it to be usable as a lib and also to provide a binary.

Currently it works fine as a binary if I am running it from its own directory, where the binary can load the bundled gems. However, if I run it from a different directory, it can't find the dependencies (they are in their own rvm gemset). I can't install it as a gem because Rubygems can't find the dependencies (currently they are listed in the .gemspec, and then told where to be found in the Gemfile).

I am currently trying `bundle package`, and it placed all the gems in the vendor/cache directory. As far as I can tell, this will mean that I need to remove the dependencies from the .gemspec and instead into the Gemfile (because Rubygems shouldn't install them since they are vendored). This means that any code using this gem will need to know about these dependencies, and add them to their Gemspecs, but I'm okay with that. I think this could work if I modify the .gemspec to include the vendored gems when building, and if I can manage the load path such that the binary sets the vendored gems at the front of the load path, but any code using it as a library will not add these to the load path, so they will get whatever versions they've installed.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that (short of reading in all the gemspecs, reflecting on their `require_paths` to add them to the `$LOAD_PATH`), and I'm not really sure that this is the correct way to handle this situation.

So, how do I make a gem that can be used as a lib, or just for its binary, when it needs Bundler to find its gems?

Answer (score 0):

if you are hosting the code in your own github enterprise instance, then it might be a good idea to have a custom rubygems server. you can then publish your internal gems to that server and have bundler retrieve them from there.

this should make a transparent workflow like you would be running your binaries in the real world!

Comment: We do have one, but there are two issues. First, Bundler is not smart enough to know to pull from the private rubygems (one of our gems was later registered on the real rubygems, and Bundler is unable to distinguish between them). And second, proper versioning and deploying adds a certain overhead. It turns out we're lazy, we just point it at the local copy and develop both in tandem, then push and update the Gemfile. This is fast and easy, few ways to go wrong. When more teams start using our gems, we'll probably be forced to version properly, but for now this is our workflow.

Comment: sure that bundler is the issue here? if you use a ci-server it should be really easy to automate the release workflow so that you can use your gems with the same ease that you are using git repos!